# Transparent VPN Server that can connect to Windows

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tunnel

I have a hosted Ubuntu server with a few extra global IP addresses assigned to subinterfaces (eth0:0, eth0:1). They're inside the same block as the primary IP address assigned to eth0 and are all fully open to the world (except as firewalled on the machine).

I'd like to be able to use one of the extra IP addresses as a VPN endpoint for a remote Windows machine. Ideally, it would be some VPN protocol natively supported by Windows so that I don't need to install custom software on the Windows machine.

Normally I'd just use something like OpenVPN, but I can't quite get it to do what I want. I want as much transparency as possible. Ideally, traffic would just be forwarded over the VPN and the Windows machine would act as if it was on the server's network. Ideally, it would have full transparency for IP traffic. Obviously, only one Windows machine would connect at a time.

Is there any Ubuntu package that will do what I want? Or is there some way to get OpenVPN to be fully transparent to inbound traffic?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is MAC forwarding.  OpenVPN is designed to work in one of two modes, either an IPVPN tunnel which has two endpoints (and therefore requires routing but has the advantage of being low-bandwidth) or MAC forwarding which operates by using a special MAC address which forwards everything, including ARP but is noisy, slow, and can have other nasty effects on your real network.  I've never successfully got MAC forwarding to work nicely with windows, though.

Comment: The real problem is windows, though.  I can't wait for them to implement GRE with encrypted endpoints so you can bind an interface the way we can do in linux.

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPNBridging) may be the solution for your problem. If not "L2 tunnel openvpn" should be the search in your favorite search engine, just as tudor said.
Please keep us posted on your progress!

Answer (score 0):

The most transparent option is [Ethernet bridging](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/). The details vary by distribution, but basically you'd start by turning `eth0` into a [bridge](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections) `br0`:

```
 iface eth0 inet manual
 iface br0 inet static
    address, gateway ...     # anything that was on eth0
    bridge_ports eth0        # just eth0 for now
    bridge_stp off           # no loop risk => no need for waits
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_fd 0
```

Pretty much anything you did on `eth0` you'd do on `br0` instead: setting addresses, iptables rules, ...

After that you'd setup OpenVPN in tap mode: your VPN clients are now in LAN with `tap0`.

Finally, as you probably guessed, we `brctl addif br0 tap0` making one big LAN with everyone. Your Windows machine can now just take an IP address on the LAN: virtually, it has an Ethernet port there.

I have done it because I needed it and it works but... **do consider giving up a bit of transparency and NATting the traffic instead**. That's just a lot easier. It may even be as simple as installing a VM, bridging it to `eth0` (ample GUI support for that) and [installing algo on it](https://github.com/trailofbits/algo/blob/master/docs/deploy-to-ubuntu.md) (almost one-click, and it easily [supports Apple, Android, Windows, ...](https://github.com/trailofbits/algo/#configure-the-vpn-clients)).